# Can't access mongodb atlas database when deployed in serverless

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

I deployed my application in aws ec2 instance and I setup the vpc peering and ip whitelist correctly and everything works fine. The app is running and I was able to access my mongodb atlas database.

Then I tried to deploy my app in serverless I wasn't able to access my mongodb atlas database. I used the same configuration I used in my ec2 server in aws. what's weird is I can access the database when I ran my app locally.

Is there any thing I'm missing? here is my config

```
# index.js
const serverless = require('serverless-http');
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient


app.get('/users', async (req, res) => {
    const url = 'mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@<cluster>/<dbname>?retryWrites=true'
    
    MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, function(err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(err)
        var dbo = db.db("<dbName>");
        dbo.collection("users").find({}).toArray((err, data) => {
            if (err) throw err
            res.send(data)
        })
    });
})

module.exports.handler = serverless(app)
```

```
#serverless.yml
service: gmt-api

custom:
    serverless-offline:
        port: 3000
        
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'development'}
  region: ap-southeast-1
  stackName: ${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}-api
  endpointType: regional
  environment:
      NODE_ENV: ${self:provider.stage}
  iamRoleStatements:
        -   Effect: Allow
            Action:
                - logs:CreateLogGroup
                - logs:CreateLogStream
                - logs:PutLogEvents
                - ec2:CreateNetworkInterface
                - ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface
                - ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces
            Resource: "*"
        -   Effect: Allow
            Action:
                - elasticache:*
            Resource: "*"
        -   Effect: Allow
            Action:
                - s3:*
            Resource: "*"
  vpc:
      securityGroupIds:
          - <security group id>
      subnetIds:
          - <subnet 1>
          - <subnet 2>
          - <subnet 3>

functions:
  app:
    wampup: true
    handler: index.handler
    name: ${self:service}-${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}-serverless
    events:
      - http: ANY /
      - http: 'ANY {proxy+}'
        cors:
            origin: '*'
            maxAge: 86400
            headers:
                - Content-Type
                - X-Amz-Date
                - Authorization
                - X-Api-Key
                - X-Amz-Security-Token
                - X-Amz-User-Agent
            allowCredentials: false
            cacheControl: 'max-age=600, s-maxage=600, proxy-revalidate'

plugins:
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-plugin-warmup
```

Comment: I would still try to whitelist ALL IPs in the mongodb atlas UI, just so you can rule it out.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up a [Network Peering Connection](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-vpc-peering/) between your Atlas cluster and your AWS Lambda function.

> This feature is not available for M0 (Free Tier), M2, and M5 clusters.

If you are using free tier than you must whitelist 0.0.0.0/0 for your Atlas cluster.

Comment: I already set up the network peering connection and it's working fine when deploying the  application in ec2, I used the same vpc for this serverless app

Comment: Hey i am late but can you tell me, those subnet are public or private ?